# Objective-C++ and UDP

Tags: iphone, udp, objective-c++

Is there an alternative to [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) written in Objective-C++? Or is it easy to convert? I need to use an UDP library for iPhone Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting valid Objective-C files to Objective-C++ is easier than 1,2,3; Simply rename all `*.m` files to `*.mm` and you are done.

Comment: But the cocoaasyncsocket library won't work then. It gives me errors like "Gcc error Pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic" on many places in the library.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Networking & Internet Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301) and [CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple docs

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by Objective-C++? Objective-C or C++?

I would look into Apple's CoreFoundation first, which is available for OS X and iOS. There is all you need for doing networking. For example there is a CFSocket class, which should be sufficient to use UDP.

CoreFoundation is implemented in C, so it should be easy to use it from Obj-C or C++ code.

Comment: I use Fmod in the same application, which requires .mm files. If I include .m files from the library or rename them to .mm the application doesn't work on the iPhone.